# Almost surely on a subset

Tags: probability-theory

I often meet in the literature on probability theory statements like "$\phi$ almost surely on $S$", where $\phi$ is a property and $S$ a subset of the underlying complete probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. The question is now, how to interprete this statement?

Option 1: Consider the measure space $(S, \mathcal{F}', P')$ where $\mathcal{F}' := \{ A \cap S \mid A \in \mathcal{F} \}$ and $P' := P|_{\mathcal{F}'}$. Then define the above property as $P'(\{ \omega \in S \mid \phi(\omega) \}) = P'(S)$, i.e. $P(\phi \cap S) = P(S)$. Note that $P'$ is not necessarily a probability measure. In the extreme case, it can also be the zero measure, if $S$ is a $P$-nullset.

Option 2: Consider the conditional probability $P(A \mid S)$ and define the property above as $P(\phi \mid S) = 1$.

The problem in option 1 is that $S$ is not necessarily an event of full outer measure which makes it a little bit strange to speak of "almost *surely* on $S$". (Of course, it would be even worse to say "with probability $1$ on $S$.) In this case one should rather say "almost everywhere" instead of "almost surely".

The problem in option 2 is that the conditional distribution is not unique in particular on nullsets. Of course, if we have a *regular* conditional probability distribution then it makes sense to speak of "almost *surely* on $S$" or even "with probability $1$ on $S$" (where "on $S$" should be rather read as "given $S$"). However, if there is no regular version of the conditional probability distribution then there are some troubles in particular when conditioning on nullsets.

So is it maybe better to introduce say option 3 (which is closer to option 1) and states:

Option 3: "$\phi$ almost surely on $S$" $:\Leftrightarrow$ $P(S \setminus \phi) = 0$.

Of course, option 1 and option 3 are equivalent and also equivalent with option 2 when we have a regular conditional probability distribution (such that we can integrate in order to get $P(\phi | S)$).

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585716/jargon-almost-everywhere-or-almost-surely-on-a-subset) is a related post which did not receive an answer to the last comment of OP which highlights the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi$ holds almost surely on $S$ means that there is a null set $N$ such that

$$\omega \in S \setminus N\Rightarrow \phi(\omega) \text{ holds} $$

This is your Option $3$. Note that this notion is only  interesting when $P(S)>0$. That is, on a null set, every property holds almost surely.

The idea to consider regular conditional probabilities is not correct since it gives you a familly of measures, and when we say that a property  holds almost surely this makes reference to a given probability measure. So stay with your original $P$. Even though you might be tempted to consider $$P'(A) = \frac{P(A \cap S)}{P(A)}$$
and note that $P'(\phi) = 1$ this means that $\phi$ holds $P'$ almost surely (in $\Omega$) not that $P$ holds almost surely in $S$ although they are equivalent. So option $3$ is indeed the right way to go since it preserves the measure in case.

Comment: Thanks. Often one considers a stochastic process $X_t$ for $t \in [0, \infty)$ and stopping times $\tau$ with $P(\tau = \infty) > 0$. Then one considers the "object" $X_\tau$ and a property of $X_\tau$ that holds almost surely on $\{ \tau < \infty \}$. In order to define this object, some authors define $X_\infty$ as some coffin state while others let it undefined (which is then set-theoretically ugly to handle).

Comment: exactly the optional stopping theorem for martingales is an example.